# Display the correct filled shape in legend of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes, legend

I have following dataset:

```
structure(list(com = c("v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", 
"v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", 
"v", "v", "v", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "v", "v", "v", "v", "v", 
"v", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t"
), d = c(0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 
0.85, 0.85, 0.85, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 
1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 
1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 1.4), strf = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.25, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 1, 1.5, 
0.25, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5, 2, 0.5, 1, 3, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 0, 0.5, 0.25, 
0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 2, 1, 2.75, 0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 2, 
2.5, 3), side = c(2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 
4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 
2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 
4, 2, 4), auf = c("h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "l", "l", "l", 
"l", "l", "l", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "l", "l", "l", "l", 
"l", "l", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", 
"l", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", 
"h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "h", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l", "l"), 
zud = c(10.8823529411765, 10.8823529411765, 8.52941176470588, 
8.52941176470588, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8.52941176470588, 8.52941176470588, 
10.8823529411765, 10.8823529411765, 9.25, 9.25, 7.25, 7.25, 
4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 7.25, 7.25, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 9.25, 
7.25, 7.25, 4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 4.25, 7.25, 7.25, 9.25, 9.25, 
8.40909090909091, 8.40909090909091, 6.59090909090909, 6.59090909090909, 
3.86363636363636, 3.86363636363636, 7.70833333333333, 7.70833333333333, 
6.04166666666667, 6.04166666666667, 3.54166666666667, 3.54166666666667, 
6.60714285714286, 6.60714285714286, 5.17857142857143, 5.17857142857143, 
3.03571428571429, 3.03571428571429, 3.03571428571429, 3.03571428571429, 
5.17857142857143, 5.17857142857143, 6.60714285714286, 6.60714285714286
), dru = c(420, 540, 420, 370, 280, 170, 410, 250, 440, 580, 
710, 530, 360, 300, 270, 240, 190, 190, 290, 270, 380, 330, 
450, 480, 320, 320, 285, 285, 190, 190, 290, 290, 420, 420, 
450, 450, 310, 300, 270, 230, 210, 210, 345, 305, 250, 270, 
205, 205, 290, 310, 270, 280, 270, 260, 340, 350, 420, 410, 
510, 500)), .Names = c("com", "d", "strf", "side", "auf", 
"zud", "dru"), row.names = c(NA, 60L), class = "data.frame")
```

and this code:

```
s <- ggplot(   data2 , aes(zud, dru))

s +  geom_point(aes( shape=com,  size=strf, fill=as.factor(d)) , alpha=0.5) + 
   scale_fill_hue(   h=c(90, -100), l=seq(80, 20,length.out = 5 ), c=90) +  
   scale_size(range = c(2 , 10)) +   
   ylim(100, 700)     + scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22)) + 
   facet_grid(side ~ auf) + 
   guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21, size=5)),    
          shape = guide_legend(override.aes = list( size=5)), 
          size  = guide_legend(override.aes = list( shape=21, fill="grey70")))
```

And that gives me this correct plot:

[image: correct]

But when I try to change the square shape into a triangle by changing this code snippet

```
+ scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22))
```

into

```
+ scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,24))
```

the legend for the shape is incorrect (empty for the second shape).

[image: incorrect]

What should I do to get the correct legend shape for this filled shapes?
(I am running ggplot2’ version 0.9.3.1 and R 3.0.1 on an Windows 64 bit machine)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this (on a mac). I see the triangle.

Comment: Strange. I restarted R and now I also see the correct shape. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a restart of R and ggplot2 the legend is displayed correctly.